# Orthodontry as a word

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, medical

When you ask search engines or dictionaries, they don't seem to recognise the word 'orthodontry' and all point to 'orthodontics' and 'orthodontia'.

I suspect 'orthodontry' is a mash-up of either of those and 'dentistry'. However, there are many businesses that use the phrase in their advertising and online communications. It seems to specifically refer to the practice of orthodontics.

Is this an example where the dictionaries are just behind the times and is 'orthodontry' just an example of a neologism on the rise - a new 'aluminum'? Or is there some good reason the word should really be avoided?

Examples of sites using the phrase:

- https://orthodonticsinlondon.co.uk/blogs/benefits-of-orthodontry.html
- https://www.columbiaasia.com/indonesia/specialties/orthodontry

There's more like it - none of them any kind of language authority on the subject, but I started looking at it because two colleagues (I live in Australia) mentioned it independently in chat, and upon asking, one shared a mail from their orthodontist that had the word in there.

Comment: onelook.com finds "orthodonture" as a synonym of "orthodontia". I can't find "orthodontry" at all with a web search. Do you have a link?

Comment: I think **orthodontry** is moribund, not a neologism. It seems the *American Journal of Orthodontry* has been renamed *The American Journal of Orthodontics*. Same thing seems to have happened to **periodontry**.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orthodontry%2Corthodontics&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Helping_Parents_Solve_Their_Children_s_B/HT0zhLMuXxUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=orthodontry&pg=PA205&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Yeah that seems pretty convincing, also no apparent reason why the new word would somehow be better or more useful.

Comment: I guess that ["aluminum"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=aluminum) was a neologism two centuries ago, but it seems strange to describe it that way now.

Comment: Every word was a neologism at one point.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I picked that example because there is a specific community that has adopted it (Americans), and the rest of the world doesn't like it all that much, so it will have that neologism 'friction' for the foreseeable future, while the world decides what English is international English. That every word was a neologism is a useless platitude in this context - the concept of a neologism is helpful when assessing the status of a word in the language. It appears 'dentistry' is not up there, it's just a common 'mistake' with little traction.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan interestingly, there's a good argument to be made for 'aluminium' being the neologism: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/06/aluminum-vs-aluminium.html

Comment: @Grismar I know; that is essentially what the link in my previous comment says. Whichever one happened to be written first is largely irrelevant, though, since the entire word (in both spellings) was basically a neologism in 1812.

Answer (score 1):

User @TimR correctly points out that the word 'orthodontry' appears to be on its way out. It is absolutely dwarfed by 'orthodontics' and 'orthodontia', with 'orthodontia' in decline as well: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orthodontry%2C+orthodontics%2C+orthodontia&year_start=1800

The word by itself appears to be past its peak, and mostly present in American English: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orthodontry&year_start=1900

As far as neologisms for orthodontics go, user @JackOFlaherty points out that 'orthodonture' appears more successful, but still not at all threatening 'orthodontics': https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orthodontry%2Corthodonture&year_start=1800

There is no evidence that there's a regional or professional preference for 'orthodontry' either, like there is with the word 'aluminum' mentioned in the question, which has remained dominant over 'aluminium' in US English.